# Выборка из DataFrame до текущего дня

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть таблица с данными. В ней есть колонки: Год, Месяц,День.
Мне нужно сделать выборку данных по текущий день.

Например, если сегодня 08.09.2020, то мне надо от 01.01.2020 по 08.09.2020

```
filtered_df = df[(df["year"] == int(year)) & (df["month"] <= now.month) & (df["day"] <= now.day)]
```

Этот код мне выдает даты по 8 число на каждый месяц от января до сентября.
Как написать правильно фильтр??

Comment: можно пример df c которым производятся преобразования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался сам

```
 res = df[(df["year"] == int(year)) & (df["month"] <= now.month)]
 slice_df = res[(res["month"] == now.month) & (res["day"] > now.day)]
 filtered_df = res[~res.index.isin(slice_df.index)]
```